# How #ifndef works in different files

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation, ifndef

So I was trying to include the libraries I have declared in my main.cpp to my header.h

```
//In my main.cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


//In my header.h
#ifndef HANOI_H
#define HANOI_H

#include <cmath>
#include <deque>

using namespace std;



#endif
```

Would this check my main.cpp to see wether the 3 libraries and namespace exist with the corresponding variable HANOI_H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because the `#include`s are performed which actually substitutes everything into 1 file. Therefore `#ifndef` never cares about multiple files or knows about them.